# Ignition GUI question: can I add my model to a running simulation?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I'm running the ~latest Ignition Gazebo built from these instructions: https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu_src

I'm learning how to use the GUI, build models using sdf, etc. My development method is "make a change to an sdf file, and restart the simulation to see what happens." Is there a better way to see a change to a model? I see in the Entity Tree widget that I can use to add a few standard shapes to a running simulation, but I don't see a way to get my models into that list. Is that possible?

Thanks!

P.S. -- if there are any cheat sheets or tips & tricks posts, please let me know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27943/ignition-gui-question:-can-i-add-my-model-to-a-running-simulation?/) by [clydemcqueen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3875/clydemcqueen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2022-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Digging into the code, I see that the Entity Tree widget only spawns the primitive shapes.

While poking around I found the Resource Spawner widget, which does exactly what I want. All of the models found on IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH appear in the "Local resources" list. The sdf for a model is reloaded every time I click on it, so I can easily make a change to the model.sdf file and quickly spawn that model into the simulation.

---

Originally posted by [clydemcqueen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3875/clydemcqueen/) with karma: 62 on 2022-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0